# Create new column using grouped column and numeric column from different data frame - R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, mutate

I have two data frames (`regionSum` and `areaSum`) shown below.

| Area | Region | void_pts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 010 | 0.125 |
| 1 | 110 | 1.566 |
| 1 | 111 | 1.350 |
| 3 | 310 | 2.004 |
| 3 | 312 | 1.652 |

| Area | void_pts |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.455 |
| 1 | 1.436 |
| 2 | 1.396 |
| 3 | 1.981 |

I'm trying to create a new column (`alert`) in the `regionSum` dataframe using these two conditions: `regionSum$void_pts >= areaSum$void_pts` and `regionSum$area == areaSum$area`.

Here is a snippet of the code that I've tried to use but its errors out.

```
t  %>% 
  mutate(alert = case_when(void_pts >= areaSum$void_pts & area == areaSum$area ~ "Red",
                                    TRUE ~ "Blue" )
```

What am I missing to give me the below results and how'd I go by tackling the same problem in the case of a lot of factors of the `area` field?

| Area | Region | void_pts | alert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 010 | 0.125 | blue |
| 1 | 110 | 1.566 | red |
| 1 | 111 | 1.350 | blue |
| 3 | 310 | 2.004 | red |
| 3 | 312 | 1.652 | blue |

Answer (score 1):

We can perform a join:

```
library(dplyr)

regionSum %>% inner_join(areaSum, by = c('Area' = 'Area')) %>% mutate(alert = case_when(void_pts.x >= void_pts.y ~ "Red",
                                                                                         TRUE ~ "Blue" ))
# A tibble: 5 × 5
   Area Region void_pts.x void_pts.y alert
  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>
1     0 010         0.125      0.455 Blue 
2     1 110         1.57       1.44  Red  
3     1 111         1.35       1.44  Blue 
4     3 310         2.00       1.98  Red  
5     3 312         1.65       1.98  Blue
```

Comment: Thanks @Karthik S. This will work. I'll just have to drop `void_pts.y` then rename the `void.pts.x`.x

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option to achieve this:

```
regionSum  %>% 
  left_join(areaSum, by = "Area", suffix = c("_region", "_area")) %>%
  mutate(alert = case_when(void_pts_region >= void_pts_area ~ "Red", TRUE ~ "Blue" ))

  Area Region void_pts_region void_pts_area alert
1    0     10           0.125         0.455  Blue
2    1    110           1.566         1.436   Red
3    1    111           1.350         1.436  Blue
4    3    310           2.004         1.981   Red
5    3    312           1.652         1.981  Blue
```

#### Data

---

```
regionSum = structure(list(Area = c(0, 1, 1, 3, 3), Region = c(10, 110, 111, 
310, 312), void_pts = c(0.125, 1.566, 1.35, 2.004, 1.652)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

areaSum = structure(list(Area = c(0, 1, 2, 3), void_pts = c(0.455, 1.436, 
1.396, 1.981)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```